# Are private keys generated by different software packages compatible?

Tags: encryption, pgp, openssl, gnupg

I know that GnuPG follows the [OpenPGP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), but if I generate a public/private key pair using GnuPG and upload the public key to a key server, i.e. the one at MIT, or use it to sign files, packages, etc. will other users who use OpenSSL, GnuPG, Putty, etc. be able to use it or descrypt the signed packages? Or do I need to generate separate public/private key pairs in all of these packages and upload the public key separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you do not upload private keys on key servers, just public keys... private keys are meant to be, well, *private*. No point in shouting them far and wide.

[OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) is a standard format for messages and keys. The *mathematical object* which is a RSA public key (technically a list of eight integers for the private key, two integers for the public key) can be encoded in many ways and OpenPGP is one of them. [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) follows this format.

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is a library (and some command-line tool) which was primarily focused on [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) and includes implementation of cryptographic algorithms. SSL uses public keys in [X.509 certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), which is *another* format, quite distinct from OpenPGP. Same kind of mathematical objects (RSA keys...), but different encoding. GnuPG internally uses OpenSSL for the cryptographic algorithms themselves, but applies its own encoding.

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) is a [SSH client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) which uses again keys (RSA, DSA...) with yet another encoding format. Again, the same mathematical objects are represented as distinct sequences of bytes.

Some people are working on [bridges](http://www.risacher.org/putty-cac/) between these competing formats. It is still a great source of inconvenience.

Comment: Yeah, that was a stupid typo. No uploading of private keys!

Answer (score 1):

All of these use the same formatting standard, so yes. In cases where a different format is used, you can *usually* generate new key containers of different types from a saved asymmetric key pair, as long as the applications you're targeting support the algorithm and key size that you're working with.

Comment: What is an example of a software package that doesn't follow this standard? I thought the three I listed, along with perhaps `makecert` and whatever GUI ones like Seahorse use internally, are the major ones.

Comment: @Frank There are other tools for things like executable signing that use alternative formats.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of these follow the same standard, yes!

Comment: So it doesn't matter which I use to generate the key pair that I upload?

Comment: Well I haven't encountered any issues yet